# error 'int' object is not subscriptable - python

Tags: python, compression, rle

im new in programming, i was trying simple code rle decompress, but im get error **'int' object is not subscriptable** in  `if (JumlahKarakter[i].isalpha() == True):` , how to fix this error?

this my code

```
TeksAsli = input("Masukan Input Teks Yan Akan Dikompress: ")
JumlahKarakter = len(TeksAsli)
Teks = ""
for i in range(0, JumlahKarakter):
    if (JumlahKarakter[i].isalpha() == True):
        for j in range(0,JumlahKarakter[i+1]):
            Teks = Teks + TeksAsli[i]

print("Hasil Decompress = ", Teks)
```

Comment: Don't you mean `TeksAsli[i]` and not `JumlahKarakter[i]`? `TeksAsli` is a string, which is subscriptable, but you're trying to subscript `JumlahKarakter`, which is just a number, since it's from `len(TeksAsli)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

TeksAsli = input("Masukan Input Teks Yan Akan Dikompress: ")
try:
    find_num = int(re.findall(r'\d+', TeksAsli)[0])
    find_text = re.sub("(\d+)", "", TeksAsli)
    Teks = ""
    for i in range(find_num):
        Teks += find_text
    print(Teks)
except IndexError:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: that's program work, but if im remove 'i+1' the program output is just **BB** if im input **B5**, i wanna trying decompres, if im input **B5**, output is  **BBBBB**.

Comment: I changed the code, can you try? as you want

Comment: thanks, program it's work. I wanna asking again. Why when im input **B10** the output just **B** not **BBBBBBBBBB**

Comment: Sorry forgot.. I tested it now and it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What you are basically trying to do in this code is you are subscripting the length of the input you have taken *(i.e len(TeksAsli) which is stored in TeksAsli JumlahKarakter)*. This will surely return an error because for example if the length is 1. You are doing something like **1[1]** which makes no sense. Secondly, in python, you do not require () parentheses to define if statement conditions. Third, you do not need to check in an if statement if the value is a bool, because if it is true it will automatically run the if statement. Here's what you can do:

```
TeksAsli = input("Masukan Input Teks Yan Akan Dikompress: ")
JumlahKarakter = len(TeksAsli)
Teks = ""
for i in range(0, JumlahKarakter):
    if TeksAsli[i].isalpha():
        Teks += TeksAsli[i]

print("Hasil Decompress = ", Teks)
```

I've removed some small errors or not needed code to improvise it. However, this above code is correct but there is a more efficient way of doing it which is:

```
TeksAsli = input("Masukan Input Teks Yan Akan Dikompress: ")
final = ''.join(TeksAsli.split(' ')) #Splits the string into list wherever space found. Then joins it without any spaces
print(final)
```

Both the programs work perfect, but the second one is more efficient and doesn't require a lot of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since `len()` returns an `integer`, stopping value of the `range()` needs to be `JumlahKarakter` instead.
I mean

```
for j in range(0,JumlahKarakter[i+1]):
```

This needs to be like this

```
for j in range(0,JumlahKarakter):
```

And the same goes to `if` statement.

Btw, Looks like you're trying to do something like this

```
text = input()
alpha = []
nums = []
for i in text:
    if i.isalpha():
        alpha.append(i)
    else:
        nums.append(i)
for j in range(len(alpha)):
    print(alpha[j]*int(nums[j]),end="")
```

You can also do it like this

```
text = input()
for i in range(0,len(text),2):
    print(text[i]*int(text[i+1]),end="")
```

Comment: that's code work, but im add i+1, for if my input B5, the output is BBBBB

Comment: @ahmuqfx see my updated answer

Comment: You're welcome! I gave you another solution at the bottom of my answer. That is the most readable and simplest answer.  Check it out